# Cómo definir nombres al generar un scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Al generar un `scaffold` en *Rails* este automáticamente me crea las rutas y nombres pluralizados, ejemplo:

```
rails g scaffold Trabajador nombre apellidos cargo
```

Y *Rails* lo genera como `trabajadors`.

Mi preguntas son:

- ¿Existe alguna forma de definir el nombre que deseo al generar el `scaffold`?, ¿alguna forma de especificarle que deseo que se llame `trabajadores` y no `trabajadors`?
- ¿Se puede cambiar una vez generado ya que he creado algunos de esta forma?

Comment: Te recomendaría no usar nombres en Español, así no tendrás este tipo de problemas, el idioma nativo de Rails es el Ingles, ahora si quieres definir tu propias reglas para otro idioma que no sea este puedes mirar estos enlaces [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html)

[ActiveSupport::Inflector::Inflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actualización**

> ¿Existe alguna forma de definir el nombre que deseo al generar el
>   `scaffold`?

Puedes especificar a rails como *pluralizar* una palabra en específico modificando el archivo `infelctions.rb`:

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb

ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'trabajador', 'trabajadores'
end
```

Después de realizar ese cambio, puedes ejecutar tu comando `scaffold` normal y el plural de `trabajador` será `trabajadores` en toda la aplicación.

> ¿Se puede cambiar una vez generado ya que he creado algunos de esta
>   forma?

Sí, realiza el mismo cambio descrito en el punto anterior (modificar `inflections.rb`) y manualmente realiza los siguientes cambios (por ejemplo, para cambiar `trabajadors`):

1. Cambia `resources :trabajadors` por `resources :trabajadores` en `routes.rb`:

   ```
   # config/routes.rb

   Rails.application.routes.draw do
     resources :trabajadores
     #...
   end
   ```
2. Cambia el nombre de tu controlador de `trabajadors` a `trabajadores` (incluyendo el nombre del archivo):

   ```
   # app/controllers/trabajadores_controller.rb

   class TrabajadoresController < AplicationController::Base
     # ...
   end
   ```
3. Cambia el nombre de la tabla para el modelo `Trabajador`:

   Crea la migración:

   ```
   $ rails g migration RenameTrabajadorsToTrabajadores
   ```

   Abre el archivo generado y modifícalo para que se vea así:

   ```
   # db/migrations/NNNN_rename_trabajadors_to_trabajadores.rb

   class RenameTrabajadorsToTrabajadores < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
     def change
       rename_table :trabajadors, :trabajadores
     end
   end
   ```

   Ejecuta la migración:

   ```
   $ rails db:migrate
   ```

---

**Respuesta original**

> ¿Existe alguna forma de definir el nombre que deseo al generar el
>   `scaffold`?

No lo puedes hacer directamente en el comando`scaffold`, pero puedes modificar el nombre manualmente una vez que ejecutaste el comando.

Por ejemplo, primero ejecuta `rails g scaffold` (a diferencia de tu ejemplo, estoy especificando el tipo de datos en cada columna):

```
$ rails g scaffold Trabajador nombre:string  apellidos:string cargo:string
```

Luego modifica tu migración para que el nombre del archivo y nombre de la tabla sea `trabajadores` en lugar de `trabajadors`, y cambia el nombre de la clase para que sea `CreateTrabajadores` en lugar de `CreateTrabajadors`<sup>1</sup>:

```
# db/migrations/NNNN_create_trabajadores.rb

class CreateTrabajadores < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :trabajadores do |t|
      t.string :nombre
      t.string :apellidos
      t.string :cargo

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Ejecuta la migracion:

```
$ rails db:migrate
```

Ahora, en tu modelo, agrega el nombre de la tabla:

```
# app/models/trabajador.rb

class Trabajador < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "trabajadores"
  # ...
end
```

Este paso es indispensable para que tu modelo no busque la tabla `trabajadors`, que es el estándar de rails.

<sup>1 * Estrictamente podrías cambiar únicamente el nombre de la tabla y con eso funcionaría bien, sin embargo recomiendo cambiar todos los nombres para mantener un mejor orden.</sup>

> ¿Se puede cambiar una vez generado ya que he creado algunos de esta
>   forma?

Sí, siguiendo los pasos arriba descritos; pero considera que, si la ya corriste la migración (y más aún, tu tabla tiene datos), deberás cambiar el nombre de la tabla sin borrarla; esto lo puedes lograr con otra migración, por ejemplo:

```
$ rails g migration RenameTrabajadorsToTrabajadores
```

Abre el archivo generado y modifícalo para que se vea así:

```
# db/migrations/NNNN_rename_trabajadors_to_trabajadores.rb

class RenameTrabajadorsToTrabajadores < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
     rename_table :trabajadors, :trabajadores
  end
end
```

Y ejecuta la migracion:

```
$ rails db:migrate
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, en mi ejemplo no especifico el tipo de datos ya que rails lo crea por defecto string si no se especifica. Eso de cambiarle el nombre a la migración lo probé y funciona, pero que pasa con las rutas?

Comment: @VicenteAlmea Mira la actualización de mi respuesta, agregué un método mucho más sencillo que te ahorrará todo el proceso que describí inicialmente, además de encargarse de las rutas de forma automática.